# SSIS solution wide global parameters or variables

Tags: variables, parameters, ssis, global, solution

I have a SSIS 2014 solution with a number of projects that all share common parameters. Is there any way to setup global parameters in SSIS (or variables for that matter) that are available for all the projects within a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in SSIS 2014 you can do it with **Environments**. An Environment is a collection of values stored as *"variables"*, either open or encrypted, with data type and description. [Description from MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213230.aspx) and [sample use](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables). So you can define a common parameter in the environment, map that environment to the Project and in the Project properties - map environment variable value to Project or Package Parameter or Connection Manager.